# How to pass parameters to a controller when using route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, routes

In my application, am loading views using ngRoute,

```
 .state('ReportViewer', {
            url: "/ReportViewer",
            controller: 'ReportViewerControl',
            templateUrl: "views/Report_viewer.html"
        })
```

I have a search Panel where users can search reports, and when selecting a report, it should route to a different page and load the report inside an iframe. Here is my code when the user select the report,

```
 $scope.goReport = function(report){
         $state.go('ReportViewer');
        }
```

I have defined a constant in the config which changes dynamically based on the report selection

```
   .constant('Digin_ReportViewer','http://192.226.192.147:8080/api/repos/%3Ahome%3Aadmin%')
```

Here i need to pass the 'Report' variable to the `ReportViewerControl` when the user select the report,

Here is my `ReportViewerControl`

```
 routerApp.controller('ReportViewerControl', ['$scope', '$routeParams','Digin_ReportViewer',function($scope, $routeParams,Digin_ReportViewer) {

    //here i need to append the report url ,
    $scope.reportURL = Digin_ReportViewer+routeParams.report ; 
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
       return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    }
}
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using ui-router for confiuring routes ,but below in ReportController you are using $routeParams.I hope you have to use $stateParams for that.

```
 routerApp.controller('ReportViewerControl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','Digin_ReportViewer',function($scope, $stateParams,Digin_ReportViewer) {

    //here i need to append the report url ,
    $scope.reportURL = Digin_ReportViewer+stateParams.report ; 
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
       return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    }
}
]);
```

also you have to pass the params from url or in method like this

```
.state('ReportViewer', {
            url: "/ReportViewer",
            controller: 'ReportViewerControl',
            templateUrl: "views/Report_viewer.html",
            params: ['report']
        })
```

Then you can navigate to it like so:

```
$scope.goReport = function(report){
         $state.go('ReportViewer', { 'report':'monthly' });
}
```

Or:

```
var result = { 'report':'monthly' };
  $state.go('ReportViewer', result);
```

Comment: TypeError: a.match is not a function

Comment: Can u describe the problem or error you are facing?

Comment: This is the error, am getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module DiginRt due to:
TypeError: a.match is not a function
    at k (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:8343)